# Creating Custom Alert box in android

Tags: android, android-widget

I know this is been answered many times but i am unable to find any good resource for this.

Can any one tell how to create **Custom Alert box** for android??. What i want is a nice looking alert box with few images text etc which will be basically mu application info. I know how to create simple alert box. Please point me to any sample code if possible

Thanks
Pranay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create any Activity you want with whatever layout you want, and apply `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` to your `<application>` tag in your manifest

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple tute, here they are adding a text box(edit text) inside the Alert box
http://www.terheyden.com/blog/?p=157
Hope it helps you
:)