# How to apply backround color and theme to alert dailog builder

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a problem in alert dialog builder. I can't change alert box background color. Please resolve my problem.

I write some code for alert builder to show alert message and icon, but I can't set background:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (id) {
        case 0:

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.alert);
            builder.setTitle("*Select Valid Location");
            builder.setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

            alert.show();
            break;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Custom Alert box in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928562/creating-custom-alert-box-in-android)

Comment: Just a heads up, you will want to return the dialog after creating it and not call `show()` since the framework will do that for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create any Activity you want with whatever layout you want, and apply `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` to your `<application>` tag in your manifest
The answer was copied from a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928562/creating-custom-alert-box-in-android)

Comment: Please don't copy answers, rather leave a comment noting that there is a possible duplicate instead.

Comment: What do you mean by layout compressed? Can you give a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

For this You need to create a style.xml in value folder and simply make your Dialog with style

http://androblip.huiges.nl/2010/05/09/theme-android-dialog/

check this link it will help You...

Comment: sry it is not working give another suggestion and my app contain more alert dailogs