# Black action buttons on a dialog

Tags: android, button, background, dialog

Just a simple question. I've created a dialog with action buttons (positive and negative). But action buttons are in light color. Is there a easy way to change them to dark? Example:

[image]

Comment: Post your code where you create your dialog. Hint: Use the Holo Light theme for your dialog, possibly with the help of `ContextThemeWrapper`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign drawable to dialog's action buttons. Design a dark color image and simply assign it to your action buttons, something like this

```
Button actionBtn = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);

actionBtn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dark_btn));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this..

```
//final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new 
      AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this,android.R.style.Theme_Dialog));

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("WorkGoal");
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("Click OK or Cancel");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.cancel() ;
            Log.v("hari", "------After OK button clicked-----------");

        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        //dialog.cancel();
            alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
           dialog.cancel() ;
           Log.v("hari", "------After CANCEL button clicked-----------");


        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();

  just refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623948/
  how-to-apply-backround-color-and-theme-to-alert-dailog-builder
```